# HTTP 406 error with rails 3.0 and internet explorer 9.0 when using render :update

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs, internet-explorer-9

I have a legacy web site based on ruby on rails 3.0.9 which works just fine with Firefox, chrome and IE 8, but I receive an HTTP 406 error every time when I check the web site with Internet Explorer 9. I narrowed down the problem to the `respond_to + format.js + render :update` trio, but I did not manage to solve the problem until now.

I created a small example for reproduction:

The action from the controller:

```
  def change
    if params[:kind]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js do
          render :update do |page|
            # originally we have a much more complicated logic here
            # ...
            page.replace_html 'list_of_numbers', :partial => params[:kind]
            # we even have this:
            # page << "changePrefix();"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The view:

```
<%= link_to("odd", url_for(:controller => "main", :action => "change", :kind => "odd"), :remote => true) %>
<%= link_to("even", url_for(:controller => "main", :action => "change", :kind => "even"), :remote => true) %>
<div id="list_of_numbers"><%= render :partial => "odd" %><div>
```

On the server side I see this:

> Started GET "/change?kind=odd" for 10.0.8.9 at Wed Jan 04 11:10:59
>   +0100 2012   Processing by MainController#change as HTML   Parameters: {"kind"=>"odd"} Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms

And the IE 9 says quite the same.

Any ideas why this doesn't work with IE9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the **1.7_rc2** version of prototype.js, which is delivered with rails 3.0.9, had some issues with `render :update`. After using the latest stable version of prototypejs (1.7.0) the problem disappeared.